# Excel: count the number of times when the 2 numbers exist in the same row in a table

Tags: excel

Count the number of times when the 2 numbers exist in the same row in a table.
For example,

1 |A B C D

2|1 2 3 4

3|1 3 4 5

4|2 4 5 6

The number of times when 1 and 2 exist in the same row in the table(A2:D4) is 1.
Row 3 and 4 are not counted.
So, how can I write the formula?

Comment: can 1 exist in the row more than once?  ie are numbers unique in the row or can their be duplicates?

Comment: No. A row does not contain duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
=(SUMPRODUCT((A4:D4=1)+(A4:D4=2))=2)+(SUMPRODUCT((A3:D3=1)+(A3:D3=2))=2)+(SUMPRODUCT((A2:D2=1)+(A2:D2=2))=2)
```

Its an ugly answer and I dont like it.  Each sumproduct is checking a row.  each check count the number of times 1 is in the row and adds it to the number of times 2 is in the row.  So for both to be in the row with no repeats the total of the sumproduct should be 2.  If that is trues then the sumproduct=2 will have a value of 1 representing true. and a value of 0 if it is not true.  Add the 1s and 0s up and you have the count of the number of rows matching your criteria.

I do not like this answer because its very specific to the sample data.  You would have to add a sumproduct row check for each additional row if you wanted to expand it.  Other may have a more elegant solution that will go through each row in an array calc.

IF helper cells are allowed it gets much easier.

Comment: I would have done it by columns. `=SUMPRODUCT((($A$1:$A$3=1)+($B$1:$B$3=1)+($C$1:$C$3=1)+($D$1:$D$3=1))*(($A$1:$A$3=2)+($B$1:$B$3=2)+($C$1:$C$3=2)+($D$1:$D$3=2)))`  But it is still just as ugly.

Comment: Can "=(SUMPRODUCT((A4:D4=1)+(A4:D4=2))=2)+(SUMPRODUCT((A3:D3=1)+(A3:D3=2))=2)+(SUMPRODUCT((A2:D2=1)+(A2:D2=2))=2)" be simplified as "sum x from 2 to 4( (SUMPRODUCT((Ax:Dx=1)+(Ax:Dx=2))=2 )"?

Comment: As I am using google sheets, I will do it by javascript. Thanks for your answer.